# Database connecting closed Gui

Tags: c++, database, eclipse, qt, qsqldatabase

I have the problem thats my programm Gui was closed.
For example I put this code in a `pushButtonClicked` method:

```
database->addDatabase("QMYSQL", "conn1");
database->setHostName("127.0.0.1");
database->setPort(3306);
database->setDatabaseName( "mydb" );
database->setUserName("root");
database->setPassword("XXXX");
if ( !database->open() )
{
    qDebug("Couldn't open DB");
}
```

It views my Gui, but when I click the button, it closes the window.
When I put this code in an init-method, it doesn't view a window.
What's wrong on this code?
The database is a QSqlDatabase. I declare it in my header.
When I delete this code, everything works normally.

Comment: The debugger is your friend, learn to use it.

Comment: database = new QSqlDatabase(); - i have delete this . Now it view's but it can't open my database ..

Answer (score 0):

`QSqlDatabase::addDatabase` is a static function. The correct form of using it is :

```
database = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL", "conn1");
```

Also note that you should use a variable of type `QSqlDatabase` as a class member not a pointer to `QSqlDatabase`.

Comment: You can define `database` as a class member like `QSqlDatabase database`. Why are you using a pointer to `QSqlDatabase`?

Comment: yes, i have delete the pointer ;) now it works so but cant open my db

Comment: Ok at-least one of your problems is solved now. This that you can not open database may be due to many reasons. May be you have not the relevant driver. Or you are not defining the correct database name, user or password. Perhaps the database server is not running.

Comment: Try to see the output of `database.lastError().driverText()`.

Comment: i have looking in the terminal, the server is running and in my terminal i can open my db. so its the right password, name and username.

Comment: model->setQuery("SELECT id, Nachname, Vorname, Ort FROM testtable"); this makes the error.

Comment: You should make sure that the database is open before making queries. Try to see the driver error text if `database.open()`  fails.

Comment: .driverText(); dont works. "driverText could not be resolved"

Comment: Try `database.lastError().text()`